# What composes the parallel structure with 'measured' in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, syntax, parsing, parallelism

Is it ***valued*** or ***set***? I have read again and again, but I am not sure either of them is better than the other. Does the comma(,) preceding ***or*** function as a guide?

> This is particularly true for people who have been valued for
> performance standards set by parents or the educational system, or
> **measured** by other cultural norms that are internalized and no longer questioned.

Comment: or measured by other internalized and unquestioned cultural norms

Answer (score 2):

"Valued" is parallel to "measured."

This is particularly true for people who have been:

- *valued* for (performance standards [that have been] set by parents or the educational system),
- *measured* by other cultural norms that are internalized and no longer questioned.

The sentence structure simplifies down to: "This is true for people who have been valued this way or have been measured that way."

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: 'measured' is parallel to 'valued'**

This sentence can be simplified to:

> This is particularly true for people who have been **valued** [...], or **measured** [...].

Normally, the `, or` doesn't need a comma. In fact, we can take it completely out of the simplified sentence I just wrote:

> This is particularly true for people who have been **valued** [...] or **measured** [...].

However, the author was being kind and provided us the comma `(,)` because there is another instance of `or` in the sentence, and did not want to confuse the reader, otherwise the sentence could have **mistakenly** be read as:

> This is particularly true for **people** [...] or **the educational system** or **measured** [...].

and this would confuse the reader, who would have to read the sentence again to understand what the author meant to say.